# jsReact trouble rendering onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change the background color of a page to one of three colors, each with a respective button. The buttons onClick function is supposed to call a function to change the color, but for some reason it is not working and instead the last button is setting the background color of the page when first loaded. Why is this? The below code is not working.

```
class Game extends React.Component
{
     setBgColor(bgColor)
     {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
     }

  render()
  {
    return(
        <div id = "buttonWrapper">
            <button id = "redButton" onClick = {this.setBgColor("red")}>RED</button>
            <button id = "greenButton" onClick = {this.setBgColor("green")}>GREEN</button>
            <button id = "blueButton" onClick = {this.setBgColor("blue")}>BLUE</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to bind the value of `this` to the component as it's currently setting to the event - read the guide on [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mickael-conner, please use the following code for defining functions for your onClick events:

```
class Game extends React.Component
{
     setBgColor(bgColor)
     {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
     }

  render()
  {
    return(
        <div id="buttonWrapper">
        <button id="redButton" onClick={() => this.setBgColor("red")}>RED</button>
        <button id="greenButton" onClick={() => this.setBgColor("green")}>GREEN</button>
        <button id="blueButton" onClick={() => this.setBgColor("blue")}>BLUE</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The following article has explained different ways for defining functions inside React components:

[5 Approaches for Handling this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56)

Comment: I got it to work by adding arrow functions in the render method for each button. from the reading that @Ben Kolya Mansley  posted, it said that class methods are not bound by default, so this means that since I never created an instance of the class with the new operator, my functions were never bound? If I add  console.log(this) under the buttons in the render function, I get Game logged to the console, even though there is no instance of game created, why is this? This occurs regardless of whether I have added arrow functions or not.

Comment: @michael-connor, you right, if we don't use arrow function for binding the function to the `onClick` event, all functions will run without waiting for the `onClick` event, so you'll see logged in the console and the last color (Blue) will be apply.
But, if you bind the functions using arrow function(or any other methods), in rendering the component, you won't see the logged in the console until you click on the button, and the appropriate color will apply to the background if you click on a button.